# how to do a hypergraph with Tcllib ::struct::graph

Tags: tcl

My Tcl application will work with a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph), i.e. edges having single-start-multiple-end or just many-ends. Looking at available live implementations I see ::struct::graph as a potential alternative. It seem however to be limited to single-start-single-end.

Is there a (preferably trivial) way of expressing hyper-edges in ::struct::graph? If not, how could I extend ::struct::graph?

(...maybe there is a better solution than ::struct::graph?)

Comment: Interesting question. I am not aware of a hypergraph-aware Tcl extension providing a tailored data structure to represent them. Could you elaborate a little: What exactly will be the purpose of a Tcl representation of a hypergraph in your application? Visualisation, optimisation problem, graph/ network analysis?

Comment: @mrcalvin Visualization. I think the polygon should be an attribute of an edge used when rendering.

Answer (score 1):

> (preferably trivial) way of expressing hyper-edges in ::struct::graph?

Not trivial, and not necessarily adequate: The only thing I could imagine right now is to use an arc's attributes to store additional pairs of source and targets for a given, well, hyperedge:

```
struct::graph myHyperGraph
myHyperGraph node insert node0
myHyperGraph node insert node1
myHyperGraph node insert node2
myHyperGraph node insert node3
myHyperGraph arc insert node0 node1 harc0
myHyperGraph arc lappend harc0 ends [list node0 node2]
myHyperGraph arc lappend harc0 ends [list node0 node3]
```

Based on this piggybacking, some processing operations should be doable with reasonable effort, e.g., into an incidence matrix.

Comment: why do you append to harc0 twice?

Comment: added thoughts of my own as answer

Answer (score 0):

Gonna post some of my progress and thoughts, allowing people to post comments.

I'm leaning towards inventing "hub-nodes".

Whenever there is need of hyperedges I make all participating nodes have edges to the hub. For a one-to-many hyperedge I would add a hub, add one edge from start node to hub, then one edge each from hub to the end nodes. For many-to-many I would add one hub and then add edges to all participating nodes. The direction of edges affects how `walk` works. I'm not sure what to prefer but it is simple enough for deciding later.

`delete` and `walk` commands will work nicely. The only issue is making a hub-node go away when its last edge is removed, but I belive this is trivial.